# Python error using subclasses

Tags: python, list, class, inheritance

can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

here is a simple code for a Python subclass to create a person, just adding the name, and I want another class that will tell  me the movies that he has rented, i'm just at the begining now

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name

class Customer(Person):
    def __init__(self):
        self.movie = []
        super(Customer,self).__init__()
```

but I get this error when I try to use my code

```
Johnny = Customer("John")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    Johnny = Customer("John"
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

I'm new at Python and I don't really know what is going on!

Comment: Python is not C++;  there is no function overloading.  Why are you defining `Person.__init__` twice?

Comment: Looks like a code block formatting problem. There's a newline missing somewhere in `self.name = nameclass Customer(Person):`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your code actually looks like this:

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
class Customer(Person):
    def __init__(self):
        self.movie = []
        super(Customer,self).__init__()

Johnny = Customer("John")
```

You should modify your `Customer` class initializer so it also takes a `name` parameter. Don't forget to pass it during `super`, too.

```
class Customer(Person):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.movie = []
        super(Customer,self).__init__(name)
```

Comment: thank you!! I can vote you up because I don't have points, I'm sorry

Answer (score 1):

You have defined the constructor for Person (`Person.__init__`) to take a single (non-self) argument named `name`:

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = nameclass
```

But when you call `Person.__init__` from your derived class constructor `Customer.__init__` you are not supplying a value for that parameter. Because Person requires `name` in its constructor, you need to supply a value for it when you invoke it.

```
class Customer(Person):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.movie = []
        super(Customer,self).__init__(name)
```

Comment: Thank for your answer!!, but, correct me if I'm wrong, isn't it the whole idea of inheritance to re-use the super class parameters, not having to declare them again in the subclasses??

Comment: @randomguy04: The idea of inheritance, at least in Python, is that any attribute you define for a child class *completely replaces* the same-named attribute in the parent class (if it exists). There is nothing which forces the child's `__init__()` to even call the parent's `__init__()` at all! That's why you have to do it explicitly if you want that behavior. And that's why Python can't assume that the parameters are going to be the same.